# Batch: using if statement to set a default path

Tags: batch-file

I'm having trouble with if/else statement.
I need to set a default path, if the field is empty.

```
@echo off
echo Parametri richiesti per generazione file Denuncie Sinistri.
set /p var0=Inserisci nome file: 
echo Nome file: %var0%
set /p var1=Inserisci il percorso del file: 
if [%~var1%] == [] ( set current_dir == %~dp0) ( echo Percorso di default %current_dir% ) 
else ( echo Percorso file: %var1% )
set /p var2=Inserisci il codice regione:  
echo Codice regione: %var2%
set /p var3=Inserisci anno di appartenenza: 
echo Anno inserito: %var3%

jre1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe -jar SimesGenerator-jar-with-dependencies.jar %var0% %var1% %var2% %var3%
pause
```

When I execute the batch, it works fine till the 2nd set,

```
set /p var1=Inserisci il percorso del file:
```

after that suddenly shuts down .batch.
Any ideas why?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: What do you think `if [%~var1%] == [] ( set current_dir == %~dp0) ( echo Percorso di default %current_dir% )` does? Are you trying to run both commands if `%var1%` is empty? (Fun fact: that line has _four_ errors on it.)

Comment: Before, it was compile like that: 
`set current_dir=%~dp0
echo Percorso di default %current_dir% 
set /p var1=Inserisci il percorso del file: 
echo Percorso file: %var1%`

I thought I could instantiate inside the if the variable var1